# Ignite Connectivity Issues

Tags: ignite, gridgain, sqlline

We have 3 Nodes of Ignite 2.7.6 cluster where we defined off heap memory/data region "datawarm" with max size 10GB and persistence enabled. We are facing very strange issue for more than a month. While connecting via SQLLine or Java Thin Client API, suddenly out of three nodes only 2 or sometime 1 node only providing the response (random order each time). After restart of the cluster the issue got resolved each time however after 3-4 hours of restart again it started. During checking the logs on the node where the connection not established only found below. We don't have any clue how to resolve this.

```
Jul 21 18:08:13 node1.example.com Ignite[6097]: 2020-07-21 18:08:13,219 DEBUG c.e.d.Logger [grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0-#30] Got client connection from address: /10.0.0.12:42262
```

Comment: Hi, please provide full logs from all nodes and the time when the issue started

Comment: @EvgeniiZhuravlev As this is our Prod systems hence not able to attach the logs out of organisation

Comment: Is there any bugs or connectivity issues reported for Ignite 2.7.6 version